# Web service request takes too much time in iPhone 5c but in iPad it is faster

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I am working on a app. In this we are hitting a web service. The problem is iPad returns response faster than iPhone 5c.

iPhone 5c takes too much time( max 37 sec).

But iPad is always consistent returns response faster(< 2 sec).

I want to know the possible reasons for this weird activity?

Comment: Same network I guess? If you do just the web service call on a new app on your iPhone 5C, still the same issue?

Comment: Compare other apps, are they behaving the same way as your app?

Comment: @Larme I tested using wifi.. but not both at the same time.. i tested it one by one

Comment: @RahulMathur other apps are working well..

Comment: iOS version in both??

Comment: @vaibby iPhone - 9.2, iPad - 8.4 & another iPad - 9.1

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in your web service and iOS code. The behaviour is sometime observed for particular device, you can try to test the app on other iPhone 5c model, it will behave in the same way as your iPad app is showing.